# ARM Cortex M3 hard fault due to 64bit address

Tags: c

My ARM Cortex M3 micro generates a hard fault error when running a C library function "localtime()". Single stepping through the localtime function shows that 64 bit addresses are being used everywhere. This didn't cause any problem until this line of code   "str     r1,[r3,r2]"    which uses a relative 64 bit address.  The GCC compiler is setup for Thumb mode. Is the compiler/linker supposed to recognize the Thumb mode, and compile/link code for that mode ?  What can I do to resolve this problem ?

Single step through localtime() function to find source of address error.

str     r1,[r3,r2]

===========================================
Make file

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include Source/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: GPS_Clock3.axf

dependents:
    -cd C:/Users/Greg/SimplicityStudio/v4_workspace/GPS_Clock3/GNU\ ARM\ v4.9.3\ -\ Release && $(MAKE) all

# Tool invocations
GPS_Clock3.axf: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) C:/Users/Greg/SimplicityStudio/v4_workspace/GPS_Clock3/GNU\ ARM\ v4.9.3\ -\ Release/GPS_Clock3.axf
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GNU ARM C Linker'
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -g3 -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -T "C:/Users/Greg/SimplicityStudio/v4_workspace/GPS_Clock3/GNU ARM v4.9.3 - Debug/GPS_Clock3.ld" -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker -Map="GPS_Clock3.map" --specs=nano.specs -o GPS_Clock3.axf "./Source/aeabi_memset-thumb.o" "./Source/crt0.o" "./Source/em_emu.o" "./Source/functions.o" "./Source/interrupts.o" "./Source/main.o" "./Source/startup_efm32jg1b.o" "./Source/test.o" -lm -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

    @echo 'Building hex file: GPS_Clock3.hex'
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "GPS_Clock3.axf" "GPS_Clock3.hex"
    @echo ' '

    @echo 'Building bin file: GPS_Clock3.bin'
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "GPS_Clock3.axf" "GPS_Clock3.bin"
    @echo ' '

    @echo 'Building s37 file: GPS_Clock3.s37'
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O srec "GPS_Clock3.axf" "GPS_Clock3.s37"
    @echo ' '

    @echo 'Running size tool'
    arm-none-eabi-size "GPS_Clock3.axf"
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS) GPS_Clock3.axf
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:
C:/Users/Greg/SimplicityStudio/v4_workspace/GPS_Clock3/GNU\ ARM\ v4.9.3\ -\ Release/GPS_Clock3.axf:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: Probably you are not using the right toolchain or passing it incorrect settings.

Comment: Is the address of r3 + r2 a valid range?  Or is it garbage?

Comment: And yes, the compiler can handle thumb to arm switching if you enabled inter-working.   But I thing that @EugeneSh. has the real answer.

Comment: I've added the make file for reference. The tool chain has been working fine for this project until function localtime() was added, and it's header file "time.h". Is there something that needs to be setup differently in the make file ?  Also, to answer Michael's question :  r3+r2 is not a valid address.

Comment: [localtime sources](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/time/lcltime_r.c)  you passed `-nostartfiles`, could be \_REENT or any locale global variable is not initialized properly. It can fail at [here](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/time/lcltime.c#L50), where is need to dereference reent. Also you are passing both `nano.specs` _and_ `nosys.specs` and then you are using `-lnosys`, specifying both makes no (little) sense. Either you want nano system or no system calls and implement them yourself, don't pass both.

Comment: I was able to remove the -nosys.specs option from the linker options, but this did not solve the problem. The make file is created automatically from various checkboxes and dialogs. However, I cannot find anything related to the -lnosys option (it is still in the make file, and I don't know how to remove it). The -nostartfiles option was selected because I am using a custom startup file. But I don't see why this would cause 64 bit addresses to be used in a lib function.